# Equality of 2 byte arrays/inline c array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, arrays, byte

I'm programming in objective-c so I can use C as well.
I have an array of bytes: (eg)

```
Byte byteArray[] = {0,0};
```

And I need to compared to another array which is hard coded. So I'm looking to do something like:

```
if (byteArray == {0,1}) {
    //do something
}
```

But there is the error "Expected Expression" on the curly braces. Is it not possible to have an inline C array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte toTest[2] = {0, 1};
if(memcmp(byteArray, toTest, sizeof(toTest)) == 0) { ... }
```

Or the easier way:

```
if(byteArray[0] == 0 && byteArray[1] == 1) { ... }
```

Comment: in the end I just used your easy way :)

Answer (score 2):

Even if the array wouldn't be "inline" you couldn't do that, because the rvalue of an array is its memory address.

You need to use `memcmp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mempcmp()`:

```
Byte otherArray[] = {0, 1};
if (memcmp(byteArray, otherArray, sizeof(byteArray)) == 0) {
    // ... equal
}
```

If you have C99 support, you could also use something like:

```
memcmp(byteArray, &(Byte[]){0,1}, 2)
```

... but in my opinion that get's quickly unreadable.

Comment: So I'm going to have to create another variable just to compare a static array?

Comment: `memcmp` has a third `len` argument.

Comment: @Jonathan: If you have C99 support you could use compound literals: `memcmp(a, &(Byte[]){0,1}, 2);`. Otherwise yes. @Thief, oops, fixed.